# STRIPE Payment integration with PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, stripe-payments

Have the below code - works fine.. BUT...  As the DB is updated to PAID before the charge, and if the charge is declined, the DB is still updated to PAID.

Want to achieve -

If charge successful and not declined, charge customer THEN update DB to PAID..

NOT

Update DB to PAID, then charge customer...

---

```
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username,$password, $database);

// Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

$sql = "UPDATE details SET PaymentStatus='PAID' WHERE MembershipNo ='12345'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
// starting the session

  require_once('config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $email = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

  $SOSamount = ($_SESSION['price']*100);
  $FirstName = ($_SESSION['FirstName']);
  $LastName = ($_SESSION['LastName']);

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
          'email' => $email,
          'source'  => $token,
          'description'  => "$FirstName $LastName - Membership"
          ));

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => $amount,
    'currency' => 'aud',
    'description' => "Membership - $FirstName $LastName"
      ));

     mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: The `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` in your if statement always gets executed first before the Stripe charge. You need to move `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` after the response from Stripe. You need to check if the Stripe response is successful. If it is then run `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap all calls to Stripe's API in a `try/catch` block to handle possible errors.

You can find more information in Stripe's API reference:

- https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#errors
- https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#error_handling

Basically, your code should look like this:

```
try {
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(...);
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(...);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // The card was declined, display an error message to your customer
    // and end execution
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Another error happened, display an error message to your customer
    // and end execution
}

// The charge was completed successfully, update your DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx altoids

Found this snippet, moved Query..

```
if ($charge->paid == true) {
            $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
            $sql = "UPDATE details SET PaymentStatus='PAID' WHERE MembershipNo ='12345'";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            }
```